# javascript execute filtering after foreach loop is completed

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, foreach, callback

I have a data from an api request and tried to store it in a temporary array using foreach and filter the temporary array after the foreach is completed.... in my case, I added a counter to compare if the counter is equal the length of api data. However, I notice that it only worked when the api data is small, say, data.length = 15 but when it reaches 20+, somehow it ignores the counter.

here's my code:

```
    var flag = 0;
    dato.forEach((el) => {
         temp.push({ 
              id: el.id,
              sex: el.sex,
              name: el.name,
              [self.momentFormat(el.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').toString()]: ({
                    activity: el.activity,
                    status : el.status,
                    record: el.record
              })
         });
         flag++;
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
        //This is what I get when I pass a parameter with date from Apr 1 to Apr 15, 
        //But when I pass Apr 1 to Apr 20... None of the logs shows up even though the api data is not empty
        console.log('dato length=', dato.length); //I get 8
        console.log('temp length=', temp.length); //I get 13
        console.log('flag length=', flag.length); //I get 8
    },5000)

    if(flag == dato.length) {
        var result = temp.filter(function(v) {
        return this[v.id]?
                !Object.assign(this[v.id], v) : (this[v.id] = v)
    }, {});
    self.overtime_dtr_records = result;
}
```

I've tried setting a timeout but I dont think its the most optimal way. Aside from defeating the purpose of fast api request, I also noticed that some of the `temporary array data` are not included in the fitlering process.

**UPDATE: I think comparing a counter to data length is correct.The problem is that when I log the length of api data, I get 45, but the loop only iterates 4 times**

Comment: Why are you referencing `self.flag` (what's `self`)? If you meant to reference the `var flag = 0` variable, you should do that by referencing the standalone `flag` variable, eg `flag++`.

Comment: Oh. small mistake, I made it global. i just inserted the code manually. I'll edit my question @CertainPerformance

Comment: Can you provide us with some sample data to run?

Comment: Did you do `console.log(flag, dato.length, temp.length)`?  They should presumably all be the same.  Or temp.length should be initial temp.length + flag

Comment: @user120242 Yep something is really wrong with the way I pushed it. I logged it outside foreach with and set a timeout but I only got the length of the dato. Does it have to do with the forEach loop?

Comment: Add the console.log to your code in the OP, just to be sure it's in the right place.  There does not appear to be any errors.

Comment: @user120242 I also noticed, usually when I pass a parameter of 'April 1' and 'April 15', It proceeds to the filtering process, but when I pass 'April 1' and 'April 20', none of the logs shows up even though the api data is not empty.

Comment: Does that actually work?  momentFormat(el.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')   is not the same as "April 1"

Comment: If none of them show up, that would seem to indicate that it never reaches the forEach loop.  Maybe it's getting cut off before it even reaches your function here?

Comment: @user120242 Yes it works, April 1 is just an example tho :). I got this format /Date(1587225600000)/..... Anyways, I noticed another thing. My api request has a date start and date end parameters. all things works when I set the date end minus 1 to the current date. lets say i pass it value of  'April 20'(that is today), it wont proceed to the process but the api data received is correct. However, when I pass it a value of anything below than 'April 20' it seems to work fine. sorry for the bad english

Comment: I've run the forEach with my own values.  No reason it would fail.  Maybe check if you have date verification functions somewhere earlier